# Remote desktop connect

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

Please don't mark this as a duplicate: I have no idea how to connect to my friend's Ubuntu 14LTS while I'm in the UK. I know there is the "Desktop Sharing" and that Remmina app, but I tried just dumping her IP in there with all the things set up on her end (i.e. allowing a connection, a password set, etc) but... no avail.
I literally have no clue what to do, and there are NO tutorials for connecting, just sharing, or Win7 to Ubuntu, or something. This is a UK-Phillipines Ubuntu 14.10 to 14LTS connection; please help me.

Thank you :)

Edit: added details.

Comment: I do not want to use the Chrome browser on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Remmina is software which can be used to remote desktop into other machines using protocols such as RDP (remote desktop protocol). To allow people to remote into your machine you need to install a remote desktop server such as XRDP on the machine you want to remote into. You can install this with

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Then to start the service you run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
```

Now (assuming firewall and other network settings permit) you should be able to connect to this machine from another using remimina. If this doesn't work you may need to look up port forwarding on your router, so that your router forwards the rdp request to the correct local machine.